# Am4Chart treemap: How to load the chart with default level to 2 in a multi-level treemap?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, treemap, amcharts4

I have a scenario where I need to load the am4chart treemap with 2nd level(index 1) instead of 1st level(index 0) in a multi-level treemap chart.

For example, https://codepen.io/avijsdev/pen/NWRQeyN has two levels of nested data( at 'children'), so by default chart loads with index 0 data, but I need to load the treemap with 2nd level data with some pre config/select parent level(index 0).

```
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

/* Set themes */
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

/* Create chart */
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.TreeMap);
chart.maxLevels = 1;
chart.data = [{
  "name": "First",
  "value": 190,
  "children": [
    { "name": "A1", "value": 100 },
    { "name": "A2", "value": 60 },
    { "name": "A3", "value": 30 }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Second",
  "value": 60,
  "children": [
    { "name": "B1", "value": 10 },
    { "name": "B2", "value": 20 },
    { "name": "B3", "value": 30 }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Third",
  "value": 190,
  "children": [
    { "name": "C1", "value": 100 },
    { "name": "C2", "value": 30 },
    { "name": "C3", "value": 20 },
    { "name": "C4", "value": 40 }
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Fourth",
  "value": 130,
  "children": [
    { "name": "D1", "value": 10 },
    { "name": "D2", "value": 20 },
    { "name": "D3", "value": 70 },
    { "name": "D4", "value": 10 },
    { "name": "D5", "value": 20 }
  ]
}];


/* Define data fields */
chart.dataFields.value = "value";
chart.dataFields.name = "name";
chart.dataFields.children = "children";
//chart.maxLevels=1;

/* Create top-level series */
var level1 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
var level1_column = level1.columns.template;
level1_column.column.cornerRadius(10, 10, 10, 10);
level1_column.fillOpacity = 0.8;
level1_column.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
level1_column.strokeWidth = 5;
level1_column.strokeOpacity = 1;

var level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
level1_bullet.locationY = 0.5;
level1_bullet.locationX = 0.5;
level1_bullet.label.text = "{name}";
level1_bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");

/* Create second-level series */
var level2 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("1");
var level2_column = level2.columns.template;
level2_column.column.cornerRadius(10, 10, 10, 10);
level2_column.fillOpacity = 0.8;
level2_column.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
level2_column.strokeWidth = 5;
level2_column.strokeOpacity = 1;

var level2_bullet = level2.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
level2_bullet.locationY = 0.5;
level2_bullet.locationX = 0.5;
level2_bullet.label.text = "{name}";
level2_bullet.label.fill = am4core.color("#fff");

/* Add a navigation bar */
chart.navigationBar = new am4charts.NavigationBar();
```